# How to fetch shipping price per package from Woocommerce order?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm searching for a way to split shipping costs between vendors (using a Vendors plugin) in Woocommerce. One solution would be to use the possibility to split orders into packages /made possible in WC 2.1).

After splitting the shipment (like this http://mikejolley.com/2013/12/manipulating-shipping-packages-woocommerce-2-1/). the  order  now shows separate shipping costs for packages and then calculates them together for totals.

Any idea where I cound find and process the shipping per package info to assign it to the vendors?

Comment: So far as I can tell, the core WooCommerce does not store these details. I am looking to do the same thing, including being able to identify which order items are linked to which shipping packages (even WC 2.3.8 does not store this). I'll post back if I find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily split shipping costs between vendors using the **Advanced Shipping for WooCommerce Multi-Vendor Plugin** along with the shipping plugins like WooCommerce UPS Shipping Plugin or WooCommerce FedEx Shipping Plugin if you are handling the shipping using UPS or FedEx. There are two options in this plugin. You can either Split and display the shipping cost separately or you can split and display the shipping cost as the sum of the shipping costs.

Here is a scenario in which the WC Vendors is used as the multi-vendor plugin, WooCommerce UPS Shipping Plugin is used for handling the shipping and the Advanced Shipping for WooCommerce Multi-Vendor Plugin is used for splitting the shipping cost: https://www.pluginhive.com/knowledge-base/ups-shipping-guide-for-woocommerce-multi-vendor-with-wc-vendors/